# sql update query

Tags: sql

I need an update query to set the null values with another value in the same group

for example

```
 Table
    filed1   filed2      filed3
    1          e         1/1/2009
    1          e         null
    1          e         1/1/2009
    2          f         2/2/2009
    2          f         2/2/2009
    2          f         null
    3          g         3/3/2009
    3          g         null
```

Expected Result

```
filed1   filed2      filed3
1          e         1/1/2009
1          e         1/1/2009
1          e         1/1/2009
2          f         2/2/2009
2          f         2/2/2009
2          f         2/2/2009
3          g         3/3/2009
3          g         3/3/2009
```

Comment: well, I suggest you write one!  When you find it doesn't work, post it here and someone will no doubt help you. SO is not somewhere where people write free code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- note table1 is your table

UPDATE t1 set t1.filed3 = t2.filed3 
from table1 t1, table1 t2
where t1.filed3 is null
and t2.filed3 is not null 
and t1.filed2 = t2.filed2 and 
t1.filed1 = t2.filed1
```

Answer (score 1):

Which database server are you using? In Oracle, this could work, assumming filed3 is equal for every row in the group or null:

```
EMPI@XE > select * from sov;

    FILED1 F FILED3
         1 e
         1 e 1/1/2009
         1 e 1/1/2009
         2 g 1/2/2009
         2 g 1/2/2009
         2 g

EMPI@XE > update sov s
  2    set
  3        s.filed3 =
  4            (select filed3
  5               from sov so
  6               where so.filed1 = s.filed1
  7                        and so.filed2 = s.filed2
  8                        and so.filed3 is not null
  9                    and rownum = 1)
 10   where filed3 is null;

EMPI@XE > select * from sov;

    FILED1 F FILED3

         1 e 1/1/2009
         1 e 1/1/2009
         1 e 1/1/2009
         2 g 1/2/2009
         2 g 1/2/2009
         2 g 1/2/2009
```